# More line styles in Matlab - without markers?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, matlab-figure, linestyle

Is there some way to plot **more than 4 line styles** in `Matlab` (as it is stated here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specify-line-and-marker-appearance-in-plots.html), I mean **line styles** **without markers**?

I 've tried https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1892-dashline but there is some problem, it does not display line correct in the legend.

Next solution for me is `gnuplot`, but I have whole calculation in `Matlab`. Is there any other advice, what other to use or what to do with `Matlab` to make more than 4 line styles? Will there be more line styles in next `Matlab` version?

Comment: There have been only four stiles since I can remember. I’ve been using MATLAB since the early 1990’s. They’re unlikely to add line styles soon. You could play with line thickness, and the most common thing is to use colors. But really, you should be asking yourself if plotting more than two lines to the same axes creates a readable plot. If they’re physically separate, you can label each line directly (use `text`). If they cross and occupy the same physical space, you’re creating a mess that is hard to read.

Comment: I agree with Cris. I really think you'll do better using markers than linestyles. But if you don't like markers, color and weight certainly add something to the line's "style".

Answer (score 1):

There are only 4 line styles, and realistically that's probably a reasonable limit in terms of legibility. But there are lots of marker styles, why not make your own "lines" by plotting close together markers?

```
x = 1:0.01:2;
a = sin(x);
b = sin(x) - sort(rand(size(x))/4);
c = sin(x) + sort(rand(size(x))/10);

figure;
hold on
plot( x, a, 'linestyle', 'none', 'marker', 's' );
plot( x, b, 'linestyle', '-', 'marker', 'o' );
plot( x, c, 'linestyle', '-', 'marker', '*', 'linewidth', 1, 'markersize', 5);
```

[image: plot]

You might need to do some interpolation to upsample your data to create the line illusion from close-together markers, `interp1` is a simple way to do this.

Although I would echo [Cris's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469926/more-line-styles-in-matlab-without-markers#comment126323390_71469926), your plot will quickly become cluttered, consider using subplots, colours, or other devices to illustrate different series and avoid chart clutter.